# SQL Server queue optimization by immediate removal

Tags: sql-server, queue

We use a table for a mail queue. When new mail needs to be sent, it is inserted into this table. There is a field in the table called status with an index on it.

A script runs every 10 seconds and checks whether there is new mail with status=0, sends this mail and then updates the status to 1 (the actual mail content is saved as a `nvarchar(max)` column).

My question: is there any benefit to immediately "cleaning" the table, meaning once an email is sent, copy the record into a different "sent" table and delete it from the mail queue table? Right now we are performing this cleaning process only once a month, removing about 500,000 emails each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must consider performance of a few operations here:

- selects of e-mails to be sent
- inserts of new e-mails
- updates of sent e-mails
- deletes of sent e-mails

To address the deletion issue right away: if you have no issues with disk space, the fastest way to delete the data is to truncate the whole table, e.g. once a month.

Insert performance should not be affected by choosing different approaches - inserts' time depends more on the table's availability (speaking of locks) and physical structure, than on the size of the table. So when it comes to locking, it would be better not to clean the rows right away (looking just at the inserts right now).

Updates of the 'sent' flag is the most tricky part here. Size of the table plays a big role, because you first need to select the rows with new e-mails and then update the row once you actually send it. I assume you use a cursor to send the e-mails one by one in a loop, so all you need is just one select statement to find IDs of all the items to be sent. That should not be resource consuming if you have a non-clustered index on the flag column. You must remember to maintain the index though, but that can be taken care of outside the business hours. Once you sent an e-mail, in order to update the flag, you can access the row using it's ID, so if you have a clustered index on the ID field (which I hope is the case), then it is a fast operation.

All in all, I would say that you would find no benefit in cleaning the table right away, because you lock it for the sake of doing it, you fragment the indexes with deletes and selects and updates would not benefit that much from that approach.

Answer (score 0):

if 10 second is justified time to run your script and volume of mail is lot then what your doing is correct.Becasue sending mail is very important than cleaning table.

cleaning process require Select -Insert,select -delete

Since you are saying 5,00,000 record per month.That measn you send this much mail per month.
so per 10 second mail=

> select 500000/30 ,select 16666/(24*60*60.0)*10=2 mail approax.

So you send 2 mail per 10 second.

I think you can do all operation at one go.Like writing trigger to move data to archive when update Status=1.

no need of second scheduler.